# Initialization of class hierarchy now fails in Swift 1.2

Tags: swift, compiler-errors

Assuming the following class structure:

```
class A : SKSpriteNode
{
    let foo : CGFloat

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { ... }

    init(foo: CGFloat)
    {
        self.foo = foo
        super.init(
             texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "test"),
             color: UIColor.blackColor(),
             size: CGSizeMake(42, 42))
    }
}

class B : A
{

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { ... }

    init()
    {
        super.init(foo: 42)
    }

}
```

With `A` and `B` being in different modules, shows the following compiler error in `B`:

> Initializer 'init()' overrides Objective-C method 'init' from superclass 'SKSpriteNode'

However, when changing `init()` in `B` to `override init()`, the following error occurs:

> Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass

Which is only solvable by adding `init()` in `A` which in turn calls the `init` of the base class.

Observations:

1. The above code did work in Swift 1.1 (i.e. without override).
2. It does work, when `A` and `B` are in the same module.
3. It does work, when overriding `init()` in `A` and using `override init()` in `B`.
4. The release notes state:

> Imported C structs now have a default initializer in Swift, which initializes all of the struct's fields to zero.

But IMO this is not related, since `SKSpriteNode` is not a `struct`.

Is this a compiler bug or did I miss something else in the release notes?

**Update** Apple fixed this in Xcode 6.3 Beta 2.

Comment: Which implementation has the error? Are you able to get it to work at all?

Comment: Sorry, for not mentioning (made an edit). The error is in `B`. I can solve it when additionally overriding `init()` in `A`.

Comment: It looks like a bug to me.

Comment: FWIW I filed a bug report to Apple.